# Hessian for linear regression with regularization

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

I'm using matlab to solve a regularized linear regression via the fminunc() function.  The cost function is from the standford machine learning class.

It's pretty slow so and I think it could be sped up if I use a Hessian multiply function via the Hessian 'on' option.

Can someone provide me with the formula for computing the hessian?  I'm a bit of a novice here.

Thanks.

EDIT:

So I think I've got it but can anyone confirm?  It's based on my less than expert attempt at calculus.  I'm using:

hessian = (X' * X + lambda * eye(length(theta)))./ m;

Comment: Coul you state the expression of the regularization you are using? Is it a "Ridge" regularization or is it more exotic?

Comment: yes, ridge regularization. (cost function penalized by lambda * sum(theta.^2))

Comment: is the hessian $X^T X$ or $X X^T$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're right (ignoring the $\frac{1}{m}$ to simplify the notation)

$$ L(\beta) = (y - X \beta)^t (y - X \beta) + \lambda \beta^t \beta $$
$$ \nabla L (\beta) = - X^t (y - X \beta) + \lambda \beta $$
$$ \nabla^2 L (\beta) = X^t X + \lambda I $$

Though, as an observation, the equation $\nabla L (\beta) = 0$ is *linear* in beta

$$ (X^t X + \lambda I) \beta = X^t y $$

so you're better off using a linear equation solver than a general non-linear optimizer.

Comment: Hi Matthew, Would linsolve() be the preferred matlab function to use?

Comment: It looks like that should work.  I'm not familiar with the ecosystem of matlab linear algebra function, so there may be a better choice that takes advantage of the structure of the coefficient matrix.

Comment: is the hessian $X^T X$ or $X X^T$?